# load a contecxtmenu from json's file using a JQuery.getJSON()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jstree

I need to load a jsTree's contextmenu from a json's file. The contextmenu is saved in this this file ("test.json"):

```
{
    "item1" : {
        "label" : "voce1"
    },
    "item2" : {
        "label" : "voce2"
    }
}
```

and the code to load the contextmenu is:

```
$(function () {

    $("#tree").jstree({ 
        "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "ui", "contextmenu" ],

        // other code ....

        "contextmenu" : {
        "items" : customMenu
    }

    })
});

function customMenu(node) {

    $.getJSON( "test.json", function(json) {
        return json;
    });
}
```

In this way, I don't see the contextmenu. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how jstree plugin works, but maybe you should try a different approach, loading first the JSON data making the Ajax request, and when it's finished, initialize the jstree:

```
$(function () {
 $.getJSON( "test.json", function(json) {
  $("#tree").jstree({ 
    "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "ui", "contextmenu" ],
    "contextmenu" : {
      "items" : json
    }
  });
 });
});
```

This is because Ajax calls are asynchronous, so your `customMenu()` function is not returning anything to your `"items"` option of `"contextmenu"`.

Comment: Aren't ajax calls either asynchronous or synchronous?